# Having trouble displaying posts from only one category in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I'm having difficulty pulling only the desired category into an archive page on Wordpress. My code is below, I thought by defining *get-category-by-slug* this would work, but instead its pulling all of the post from every category into the page.

```
<?php
    $category = get_category_by_slug('weddings');
    $args = array(
                 'post_type' => 'elp_projects',
                 'posts_per_page' => 12,
                 'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1)
                 );
    query_posts($args);
    $x = 0;

    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this would be appreciated.

I've also tried these combinations with no luck.

```
<?php
    $category = get_category_by_slug('weddings');
    $args = array(
                 'post_type' => 'elp_projects',
                 'posts_per_page' => 12,
                 'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1)
                 );
    $query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=weddings' );
    $x = 0;

    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
```

and

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=weddings' ); ?>
```

and

```
<?php
    $args = array(
                 'post_type' => 'elp_projects',
                 'posts_per_page' => 12,
                 'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1)
                 );
    $query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=weddings' );
    $x = 0;

    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do not use `query_posts` its not the best way to query data its a [**last resort**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts#answers-header)  if you will.

Instead use `WP_Query` to get posts from one category just do `$query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=staff' );` refer to this [**page**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) for more information on how to get posts from one category using `WP_Query`.

**EDITED**
Try this

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'category_name' => 'wedding', //name of category by slug
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'posts_per_page' => )); // how many posts to show

  // Put into the loop
  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
   $the_query->the_post();
   echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
  endwhile;

  // Restore original Post Data if needed
  wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: @David Chase, actually this doesn't seem to be working for me, David. When I changed my original query to the one you supplied, using the proper category slug of course, and now no posts are being loaded on to the page...

Comment: did you check out the codex in my answer, and please update your question code so i can see what you are doing code wise.

Comment: @David Chase I checked it out, but am obviously not grasping the concept fully. I'll update the question now.